# jq: error: Cannot iterate over string

Tags: jq

could someone please explain below warning?

input file is:

```
{
 "env": "DC",
 "hosts" :
[
{
  "apt_update_last_success": "1495991703",
  "architecture": "amd64",
  "hostname": "h1"
},
{
  "apt_update_last_success": "1495991703",
  "architecture": "amd64",
  "hostname": "h2"
},
{
  "apt_update_last_success": "1496045706",
  "architecture": "amd64",
  "hostname": "h3"
},
{
  "apt_update_last_success": "1496045705",
  "architecture": "amd64",
  "hostname": "h4"
},
{
  "apt_update_last_success": "1496049305",
  "architecture": "amd64",
  "hostname": "h5"
},
{
  "apt_update_last_success": "1496049307",
  "architecture": "amd64",
  "hostname": "h6"
}
]
}
```

the jq command returns what expected but also prints the warning I dont know why:

```
$ jq -r '.[][] | select(.hostname=="h6")' ddd.json
jq: error: Cannot iterate over string
{
  "apt_update_last_success": "1496049307",
  "architecture": "amd64",
  "hostname": "h6"
}
```

please tell me how to get rid of this.

thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is in your notation `.[][]`. Your input is just an ***object*** but you are trying to present it as a "container" of "containers" `.[][]`.

The right way is:

```
jq '.hosts[] | select(.hostname=="h6")' ddd.json
{
  "apt_update_last_success": "1496049307",
  "architecture": "amd64",
  "hostname": "h6"
}
```

---

Besides, on *jq* **1.5** this `jq -r '.[][] | select(.hostname=="h6")' ddd.json` doesn't return the expected object but only prints 
`jq: error (at jq1:36): Cannot iterate over string ("DC")`

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when piping a log file with a list of individual JSON objects to JQ:

```
$ cat my_log_file.txt:
{"message": "foo"}
{"message": "bar"}

$ cat my_log_file.txt | jq '.message | unique'
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot iterate over string ("foo")
jq: error (at <stdin>:2): Cannot iterate over string ("bar")
```

In this case you need to use jq's command line option `-s` (slurp) so that you can operate on the file as a single array object.

```
$ cat my_log_file.txt | jq -s
[
  {
    "message": "foo"
  },
  {
    "message": "bar"
  }
]
```